# Unity VR build shows 4 screens i.e. 2 screens on each eye

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

[image: issue image screenshot]

Using GoogleVR SDK and gazeinputmodule setting position using eyeTexturewidth/2 and eyeTextureHeight/2.

- Unity 5.4.
- Device tested on Note 4.
- Target is supposed to be Gear VR.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Gear VR you don't need to use the GoogleVR SDK, that's for Google Cardboard and for Daydream.

Go to Player Settings (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player), and tick the "Virtual Reality Supported" checkbox:

[image: VR Supported]

If you are just starting with Unity and VR development, I suggest you take a look at the free samples provided by Unity for Oculus and Gear VR: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/51519